# How to call a cloud-function via PHP

Tags: php, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm a newbie to firebase/cloud-functions etc..
for the first time and I wrote a cloud function for my test website that stores data from an html form into fire-store database (Name,E-mail passed to the function from the form on submit) via https trigger.

For security i restricted the function (set permissions for service accounts).

For testing i just used barer tokens on Authorization header filed with postman and from my PHP file. But they expire within 1Hr~

So whats the correct way i can do this?
What kind of token should i use? (I have the service account key (pid-...*.json file) but don't know how/what to do with it)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the REST API with cloud functions, you should be tracking when the last time your token was last refreshed or simply manually refresh it before making the HTTP request.

You can refresh the ID token with the refresh token per the documentation

```js
Method: POST
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=[API_KEY]
```

**Request Body Payload**

- grant_type    string  The refresh token's grant type, always "refresh_token".
- refresh_token string  A Firebase Auth refresh token.

Source:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-refresh-token